# Is there a way to run commands over multiple R datasets?

Tags: r

I am very new to R and would like to use some code to run various batch code on all of the data that I have available. It should be clear what I'm trying to do:

```r
# library(PerformanceAnalytics)
# mydata <- mtcars[, c('mpg', 'cyl', 'disp', 'hp', 'carb')];
# chart.Correlation(mydata, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)

library(MASS)
M_names = data(package = "MASS")$result[, "Item"]
for (i in 1:length(M_names)) {
    eval(paste("MASS::", M_names[i], sep=""));
}
```

The commented part is some code I found that I haven't been able to integrate yet. The `Correlation` is a very cool correlation matrix, which I'm attempting to funnel every single dataset I have access to into so I can quickly review them instead of doing it all manually. I guess I will need to save them all to PNGs to have practical workflow around that, as it's clear there's no way to coax the X windows to appear or stay put when running R code as a script.

The behavior I observe as I execute this on my Mac is:

```
> library(MASS)
> M_names = data(package = "MASS")$result[, "Item"]
> for (i in 1:length(M_names)) {
+       eval(paste("MASS::", M_names[i], sep=""));
+ }
>
>
```

I don't know for sure what the silent `+` indicator means, but I'm pretty sure it just means that code line is inside the for loop scope. But the `eval` is swallowing the command I assembled. I'm just trying to get it to print out the content of the data at each iteration of the loop for now.

I also noticed this:

```
> eval("MASS::ships")
[1] "MASS::ships"
```

It just prints it when I try to eval it.

I also hope there is a way to programmatically print individual datasets. I'm already hacking really hard at this, and there is no way that what I am doing here is a good idea.

Comment: Not sure why it got tagged javascript, thanks for the correction.

Comment: If you actually are wanting to use the datasets from a package, you can load them in one call and use `get` to grab the object from the character string i.e. `M_names = data(package = "MASS")$result[, "Item"]; data(list=M_names, package="MASS"); for (DATA in M_names) {print(summary(get(DATA)))}`. However, if you have a bunch of datasets in your global environment, it is probably easier to hold them in a list. Then you can just loop through them i.e. `list_of_dataframes = list(mtcars, iris) ; for (DATA in list_of_dataframes){ print(summary(DATA))}` (I use summary instead of chart.Correlation)

Comment: ... ps for reviewing a bunch of plots you may find it easier to output to one document , using markdown or sweave, rather than a bunch of image files

Comment: hi @user20650, thanks for your comments. The core of my problem is that I cannot come up with a R way to obtain the `list_of_dataframes` list itself, programmatically. I am not interested in typing out 120 dataset names into a list. I will use bash to compile such a string to paste into R in the meantime.

Comment: Its difficult to suggest anything without knowing your workflow. Normally when I have multiple dataframes, I have either read then in so they are stored in a list (e.g. `lst_of_dataframes = lapply(path/to/files, read.table)`) or I have split a data frame (e.g. `lst_of_dataframes = split(big_dataframe, big_dataframe$group_indicator)`). So you do not need to type the individual names in using either of these ways, only iterate through the list)

Comment: Makes sense. I'm looking at datasets that come with packages from R. It's ok, I came up with the bash machinery already. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also your `M_names = data(package = "MASS")$result[, "Item"]` does what I was asking for. I didn't look at your comment closely enough. You should put it as an answer...

Comment: And the key is the `get` function

Comment: just had a wee thought. It may be worth addiing the data to a new environment instead of polluting your workspace. You can do that with `data(list=M_names, package="MASS", envir = list_of_datafames<- new.env())`. You can then look through `list_of_datafames` as you would with an pther list object: `lapply(list_of_datafames, summary)`

Answer (score 1):

If you have the package dataset names in a vector the key to accessing them
by their character names is the `get` function:

```
library(MASS)
M_names = data(package = "MASS")$result[, "Item"]

head(get(M_names[1]), 1)
#    state sex  diag death status T.categ age
#  1   NSW   M 10905 11081      D      hs  35
```

You can then loop through the vector of names

```
for (DATA in M_names) print(summary(get(DATA)))
```

Another options is to use the `envir` argument of the `data` function to load the datasets into a specific environment. It may be worth adding the data to a new environment instead of polluting your workspace.You can do that with

```
data(list=M_names, package="MASS", envir = list_of_datafames<- new.env())
```

You can then look through the `list_of_datafames` as you would with an other list object:

```
lapply(list_of_datafames, summary)
```